# Lookup search modal not working for lightning-input-field component in lightning out for LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning-out, lightning-data-service, lookup-field

As visible in the screenshot below, The lightning-input-field component along with lightning-record-edit-form is used to generate this view. LWC is embedded inside the Visualforce page using the lightning-out feature. But the lookup field Case Manager is not displaying a full-screen search modal instead it's displaying the exception message "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [Cannot read property 'ma' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {markup://lightning:deprecatedOverlayUtils}".

Please suggest workarounds to fix this issue.

[image]

Below is the expectation:
[image]

Relevant Code:

```
<!--VF Page-->
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" standardcontroller="Case" recordSetVar="records" extensions="ExtendedController">
<apex:includeLightning/>

<div id="LightningAppDivId"></div>

<script>
    $Lightning.use(
        "c:SampleLightningOutApp", 
        function() { 
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:sampleLWComponent", 
                {recordIds: "{!recordIds}"}, 
                "LightningAppDivId" 
            );
        }
    );
    </script>
</apex:page>

<!--sampleLWComponent.html-->
<template>
...    
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case">
    <lightning-input-field 
        name="EntityId"
        required variant="label-stacked" 
        field-name="Case_Manager__c" <!--Lookup Field-->
        onchange={handleInputFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
...
</template>
```

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: @Max Updated question with sample code.